# Multivariate Test with a Reference Group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

I don't have enough knowledge of Multivariate Statistics to describe my problem in formal terms, so I'll give you a concrete example of what I want to do.

Suppose a clustering algorithm **C** that is well-known and widely used, but very slow. The output is an N-D vector with a cluster assignment for each of the N points of the original data. There is some randomness involved, so if you run **C** many times, the results will all be slightly different. It should be no problem comparing two of the results with some pairwise similarity measure, so one could compute the variance of these results to arrive at some kind of "natural" or "acceptable" range of variation, but I don't think it makes sense to compute a centroid.

Now suppose someone comes forward with a new implementation **C$_1$** that is, supposedly, 100x times faster but yields "equivalent" clusters. I would like to test the null hypothesis that the results are indeed the same, i.e., that the cluster assignments from **C$_1$** come from the same probability distribution as **C** or, in other words, that the variation against results from the original **C** is within an acceptable range.

My first idea was to try to reduce the problem to a univariate testing scenario as follows: (a) pick a dataset; (b) take two large samples, $S_1$ from **C** and $S_2$ from **C$_1$**, using the same hyper-parameters; (c) reduce each clustering result (N-D) to one value by computing its average similarity against all the samples from $S_1$, so now both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are univariate samples; and (d) use some non-parametric test such as Mann-Whitney's U to determine if the values from $S_2$ come from the same distribution as $S_1$ (which represent the acceptable variation range). 
Please note that all data points would be compared against $S_1$, since I'm not necessarily interested in the internal variance of $S_2$. That is why I mentioned a "reference" group in the title, which in this case would be $S_1$.

Does the solution above make any sense? If not, what would be the right way to go forward with this?